# facebook graph api does not return all feed items on facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

at the time of this question, if you go here:

http://www.facebook.com/realplayer

you'll see six posts down, I have posted a photo with a message of "#highfive Cincinnati, OH"

but if you to either of these:

http://graph.facebook.com/realplayer/feed
   http://graph.facebook.com/realplayer/tagged

the JSON that is returned seemingly includes everything on the wall, except for MY post.  there is another photo post from someone else down below mine, and it is showing up (and both my photo and his photo are in the "Fan photos" section)

obviously, since I can see everything with these links already, it appears that access_token is not a part of the equation... BUT, some more info:

- if I use an access_token from a session that isn't me, I can't see the post in the JSON
- if I use an access_token from MY logged in session, then I DO see the post in the JSON

so I'm very confused.

if everyone  in the world can see those posts on the wall without even authenticating, then I expect all of them to come back in the graph api as well.

anyone have thoughts on this?

---

I am aware of the "manage_page" permission... which I can use to get a list of accounts and special offline access tokens for those pages... and that's something I can explore... but it seems like alot of work when my post seemingly SHOULD be there in the graph

Comment: Hi Nick, seems we have a similar issue, not exactly though - still might be interested - see my posting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622096/facebook-graph-api-feeds-missing-in-json-response

Comment: Hi Matias.. I was actually just looking at your post... but I can't get my issue resolved with FQL either (see my updated answer below).  grrrrrrr

Comment: I think it's recommended by FB to always append the access token to the grap api URL. Without an access token, the feeds url behaves a little 'random'. Haven't found any other way except adding the access_token always.

Comment: well as I explained below, I've actually tried it with all the access token types I can think of (user session token, application token, page impersonation token) and none of them work for a couple of guys on that page (almost feels like they have somehow set their security to "don't show me in the API")

Comment: has anyone figured out the answer to this problem yet?  I still have this issue as well.

Answer (score 5):

well looks like FB has this nice little anti-spam feature for pages... such that a non-admin can't write lots of messages on your page.   what's interesting is that facebook uses similar "silent treatment" techniques that StackOverflow uses ( https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/podcast-21/ )... so when I look at a wall that I've been "spamming" I will see all of my posts... but no one else will.

I was able to create a new test account and get about 3 or 4 messages on a page before it started blocking me again

so probably the Graph API is working as designed  :)

========================

UPDATE:  this appears to only be part of the problem.  I have constructed another page and app and been doing testing:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/RP-Test-Page/116735865065591

note the entry for "#highfive Orlando, FL" ... even an unauthenticated user can see this entry from the actual page... but there is seemingly no way for me to get it back through the API.  He only posted once, so it can't be an "anti-spam" thing (you wouldn't think).

I have obviously tried the Graph API (with and without my own access token)

I have tried FQL (with and without my own access token)

and I have followed this post:
http://en-gb.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=10381469571&topic=3815&post=51980
in order to request manage_pages and offline_access extended permissions from myself and use that to get the /me/accounts and then get the "impersonation" access token (whew)... STILL NOTHING

there must be some other super security thing going on.  is it not possible to reliably get all of the wall posts from a page?

Comment: You ticked your own answer as accepted - but did you actually really solve this issue in the end?

Comment: This answer should not be ticked, as people like me are still looking for one.