# Graph API quotas?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know what are the content limitations in Facebook Graph API?

I noticed that using the API returns less results than the user interface. I couldn't find neither any logic in the quantities nor an appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some posts which, for whatever undocumented reason, don't show up in the Graph API. This [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617606/facebook-graph-api-does-not-return-all-feed-items-on-facebook-page) [new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622096/facebook-graph-api-feeds-missing-in-json-response), and may in fact be a feature of the Graph API (some obscure privacy setting maybe? I dunno). Whatever the case, it's not documented.

As far as quotas go, I have apps that have run through hundreds of thousands of API requests in a matter of days with no problem, and as far as I'm aware, there's no quota system in place (at least not currently).

Comment: When I try go get historical posts from a page it stops at a certain point (empty results). So far it happens for all of my test pages. I manage to get a couple of hundred posts and that's it.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried getting all posts from my wall, and there are random chunks that are just missing. It's just the way it is, unfortunately. You could try clicking "download a copy..." on the [facebook settings page](https://www.facebook.com/settings) to get an archive with all your posts.