# The owner of the wall does not see shared posts, but the poster sees them

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am developing an application that is supposed to get all posts on a user or page wall. For that purpose I use an fql query like this one:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT source_id, post_id, actor_id, app_id, viewer_id, created_time, updated_time, target_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = A order by updated_time desc
```

I noticed the problem when testing with the Graph API Explorer for an user A, that some posts (having links if that is relevant? ) on A's wall made by B are not available. 
The problem seems somewhat consistent as they are also not available with:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/A/feed
```

When I open the Graph Explorer with B and use the same queries I can see the missing posts.

Both A and B are friends. In the examples the user id is used instead of A and B respectively. The permissions requested for the access_token are 'read_stream', but even with additional permissions there seems not to be any difference.

Could that be a bug, related to [facebook graph api does not return all feed items on facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617606/facebook-graph-api-does-not-return-all-feed-items-on-facebook-page) or perhaps some reincarnation of http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10576 ? Another thing I am thinking is that it is related to the current changes that Facebook is making in the API. If someone has any insight it will be much appreciated.

Comment: To make thing even more weird - a post with link by user C is listed for both A and B, and a post from B without a link in it is also available.